# Parallel reductions with complex objects

Tags: parallel-computing

Typically (from what I can tell) reduction operations produce a "number". This makes them easy to deal with since there isn't really any memory overhead.

However, I have something that I'm working on where I want to combine instances of a nontrivial data structure. That is, if `x` and `y` are instances of some class `C`, I have an operation that combines `x` and `y` into another object `z` of class `C`. Let's write `z=a+b` where `+` is my operation from pairs of `C` to `C` (mathematically, `+:C x C -> C`).

I already have an efficient implementation of `+`, but I'm struggling to get my memory allocations under control when doing a (parallel) reduction on a list of instances of `C`.

Are there some standard approaches or research related to this problem? In essence I want to reuse memory without reallocating as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you use MPI to implement your parallel program, you can define your own reduction operator (besides using standard, predefined operators). This allows implementation of complex, user's defined reduction.

In particular, your object instances A and B are respectively the first and the second parameters of the function required to implement your reduction, and the result is returned through the second parameter. So, the second parameter is used for both input and output, and you can avoid allocating a temporary object that will contain the result to be returned, since you can modify on the fly the second object.

You may still need a few temporary variables to compute the intermediate partial results to be stored in the fields of your object, but the memory required should not be that much.

Anyway, it is worth recalling here that you can not use a C++ object for this: you will neeed to build a custom derived datatype to represent your C++ object (MPI provides many different APIs for this purpose), and you will need to serialize your objects into custom derived data types for the reduction and to deserialize the custom derived data type which is the result of the reduction back to your C++ object.

Comment: Hi, someone else proposed a similar thing for the one-computer case (which works very well, by the way). I'm not using MPI at the moment but I may look into it for later to do distributed computing.  Thanks